Relation between microservices postgresql
I'm working on a side project for my university, which consists of several applications (currently, just a journal and a live chat). At the moment, I have implemented chat and user microservices. In my chat database, I only have the IDs of the people sending messages. I want to establish a relation between the messages in my database and the names of the senders in my user database. However, the approaches I've considered so far involve communicating with my API and sending the entire user database to my chat API to connect every single message to every single username. However, this approach will not scale. I've also considered simply adding a nickname to the database and calling it a day, but I don't think that would be good practice. What you guys think is the best approach?

